# Looking for a pair of adjoint functors

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, adjoint-functors, universal-property

I'm struggling with finding the left adjoint to a functor, and the right adjoint to another one. Here's some context.

Given any ring $R$, we can associate two categories to it. The first one is a POset, which I will denote by **Hom(R)**: its elements are ordered pairs, $(a,M)$, where $a=\ker\phi$ and $M=\phi^{-1}(U(S))$, for some given ring morphism $\phi$ of $R$ into an arbitrary ring $S$ ($U(S)$ denotes the group of invertible elements of the ring $S$); the partial order on it is defined as follows:
$$(a,M)\leq(a',M')\quad\iff\quad a\subseteq a', M\subseteq M'.$$

The second one, which I will denote by **R-Rings**, is the one whose objects are the ring morphisms from $R$ to another ring $S$, $\phi\colon R \to S$, and such that, given any pair of objects, $\phi\colon R\to S$ and $\phi'\colon R\to S'$, the morphism between them are exactly the ring morphism $f\colon S\to S'$ that form commutative triangles with the given morphisms, i.e. that make the following diagram commute

[image]

Given any pair $(a,M)$ defined as above, it is possible to prove that there is a canonical ring morphism that "realizes" that pair, which I will denote by $\psi\colon R\to S_{(R/a, M/a)}$; besides, this morphism is universal in this sense: given any ring morphism $\phi'\colon R\to S'$ such that $(a,M)\leq(ker(\phi'),\phi'^{-1}(U(S))$, there exists one and only one morphism $g\colon S_{(R/a, M/a)}\to S'$ such that $g\psi=\phi'$.
Given these facts, we can observe that the functor 
$$A\colon Hom(R)\to R-Rings$$
which maps an ordered pair $(a,M)$ to the canonical morphism that realizes it, and the functor
$$B\colon R-Rings\to Hom(R)$$
which maps a morphism $\phi\colon R\to S$ to the pair $(\ker(\phi),\phi^{-1}(U(S)))$, form a pair of adjoint functors (A is left-adjoint to B and B is right adjoint to A), since for every $(a,M)\in Hom(R)$ and every $\phi\colon R\to S \in R-Rings$, we have
$$Hom_{R-Rings}(A(a,M),\phi\colon R\to S)\cong Hom_{Hom(R)}((a,M),B(\phi\colon R\to S)).$$
I've been trying to find a left adjoint to $A$ and a right adjoint to $B$, but I couldn't figure them out. 
I'll be thankful to anybody who'd like to give me some advice.

Comment: Why the functor $A $ would have a left adjoint?

Comment: I was asked to prove that A is left-adjoint to B and B is right adjoint to A (and this was quite easy, as shown above); moreover, I was asked to find a left adjoint to A (and a right adjoint to B), but I have no guarantee they exist.